# Asynchronous Serialization for Winform Optimization

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, optimization, xml-serialization

I'd like to do something like AJAX for our Winforms apps to optimize data delivery. I'd also like to cache info about user behavior (frequently used, recently used, etc.).

[Juval Lowy's ideas on component architecture](http://bit.ly/fxWoKP) and serialization got me pretty excited when I was a newbie to C#, but where the rubber meets the road I'm one guy in a small company: overly elaborate solutions can get me in trouble and code reuse can be a simple as the Windows clipboard.

What authors, design patterns, or cautionary tales should I consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX for Winforms can be accomplished with the [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), the cache can be implemented easily by creating in Program.cs static dictionaries that you'll fill at application start from database. I advise you to always check how much memory is available and compare this with an estimated size of your cache dictionaries, this can be done by using the [MemoryFailPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the MemoryFailPoint class. That could be pretty handy when I'm building caches.